# How to check a Windows Store app on the left or right of screen when it's in snapped state?

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-metro

I want to check position of a Windows Store app when it's in snapped state (left or right of the screen) by code. If it's on the left, I do something. If it's on the right, I do something else.

How to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the Left edge of the [Current](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.window.current.aspx#Y193) window in conjunction with the [ApplicationView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.viewmanagement.applicationview.value.aspx)

```
if (Windows.UI.ViewManagement.ApplicationView.Value == Windows.UI.ViewManagement.ApplicationViewState.Snapped)
{
    if (Window.Current.Bounds.Left == 0)
        // snapped left
    else
        // snapped right
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can detect which side the App is snapped to. You can detect if app is snapped, filled, FullScreenLandscape and FullScreenPortrait and that's about it.

[Windows.UI.ViewManagement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.viewmanagement.aspx) namespace doesn't provide any function for position of snapped state.

**Update**

As **Jim O'Neil** said, following code works perfectly.

```
if (Windows.UI.ViewManagement.ApplicationView.Value == Windows.UI.ViewManagement.ApplicationViewState.Snapped)
{
    if (Window.Current.Bounds.Left == 0)
        // snapped left
    else
        // snapped right
}
```